# Datatables integration with ace admin theme

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, yui-datatable

I have integrated vertical scrollable datatables(server side using `sAjaxSource`) with the `Ace Admin` theme for reponsiveness (bootstrap,ace.min.css/js) files etc.

The moment I integrated it with Ace theme for responsiveness it displays 2 `thead`s. The 2nd `thead` is a static one which displays only sorting icons that do not work but the 2nd header is properly aligned.

The first `thead` which is formed as a result of `aocolumns` attribute of datatables is not at all properly aligned and is not at all responsive.

I have tried these solutions to remove the header:

1. using `fnColumnAdjustSizing`
2. a `div` outside the table
3. border property set to `seperate` and `all`
4. using callbacks

Here is the url for the datatatable issue I am facing...

It is basically a static json file the datatable is reading; that is why the numbering is not accurate.

http://qait.qaitdevlabs.com/acedemo/tables.html